# How to include last coefficient column

Tags: r

I have a model called mymodel. The following returns all the coefficients except the last column with the asterisks. How do you include the asterisks column?

```
summary.lm 
coeffs <- summary(mymodel)$coefficients 
coeffs
```

Comment: Can you add some data using `dput` to make this post reproducible? Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: In addition to Ben's answer below, you may also find the result of `broom::tidy(mymodel)` useful as it returns a cleaned up dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

This information is not actually stored anywhere, it's printed by `stats::printCoefmat`.  In order to retrieve it we have to copy some code out of the guts of that function.

Example using a built-in data set:

```
m <- lm(Murder~Assault+UrbanPop,data=USArrests)
```

Retrieve the coefficient table from the summary:

```
ss <- coef(summary(m))
```

Extract the p-values:

```
pv <- ss[,"Pr(>|t|)"]
```

Format the significance stars:

```
Signif <- symnum(pv, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, 
              cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), 
              symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " "))
```

If you want to get rid of the legend, `attr(Signif,"legend") <- NULL`.

Or you could just `printCoefmat(ss)`.

Comment: Can it be included to save to a data frame without this:
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Comment: @tinafmills Try `printCoefmat(ss, signif.legend=F)`.